# cross compiling libqsqlmysql.so from ubuntu to raspberry pi

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, qt-creator

I made an application using qt creator for my raspberry pi on my ubuntu laptop. I have figured out how to cross compile the program, but I get a:

> "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded.
>
> QSqlDatabase:availible drivers: QSQLITE
>
> could not connect

whenever I try to connect to mysql database. I believe that this is because I do not have a libqsqlmysql.so in my plugins directory. When I try to build what I think is the code, I get no output. It appears like it was a successful build, but there is not output. How can I compile this/where could I download it?

Comment: Apparently you also need to compile the mysql binding for Qt